# iPhone Obj-C - Retrieve custom object from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, object

Having:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSString *name; // retained and synthesized
    NSString *address; // retained and synthesized
}
```

I'm creating an array:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray; // retained and synthesized
```

Filling it with several MyClass objects:

```
MyClass *kat = [MyClass new];
kat.name = @"somestring";
kat.address = @"someotherstring"
[myArray addObject:kat];
[kat release];
```

How can I get object at some index? The code below keeps giving me null but it should illustrate what I need..

```
MyClass *obj = (MyClass*)[myArray objectAtIndex:5];
NSLog(@"Selected: %@", obj.address); // = null :(
```

Is it something wrong with casting or I'm forgetting about something?

Comment: Have you actually created the `NSMutableArray *myArray`, or only declared it? You'll need a line like `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` somewhere.

Comment: you should check the contents of your array in nslog first, if that is null then may be you should show us the code where you have initialize your mutable array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyClass *obj = (MyClass*)[myArray objectAtIndex:5];
NSLog(@"Selected: %@", obj.address); // = null :(
```

If that code is printing `(null)`, it *cannot* be because the array is empty or `objectAtIndex:` failed.  `objectAtIndex:` will throw a range exception if you try to access an index beyond the count of objects in the array and an array cannot contain "holes" or nil references.

The only way that code will run without incident is if:

- `myArray` is nil;  you didn't allocate and/or assign an array instance to `myArray`.
- `obj.address` returns nil;   you didn't correctly initialize the instance (which it appears you did).

Comment: Wow, such a simple mistake, I concentrated on the MyClass object instead of myArray and I really didn't alloc it. But I'm still learning, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to just declare myArray in an @property/@synthesize pair.  You need myArray to be non-nil as well. You need to add 
`myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
somewhere above your `[addObject:]`call.

Additionally, since you've declared the "myArray" variable as retain, if you set another (non-nil) array to myArray through `self.myArray = otherArray` myArray will be non-nil and retained and ready to accept objects.

Also, if you allocate myArray, don't forget to release it in your class's dealloc method.

Comment: Better to create it with "self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array]". Otherwise you'll need to release it *twice* - once to balance the ownership implied by the use of +alloc, and again to balance the assignment to a retained property.